# Did PDF and so mozillas pdf.js ever used the SHA-1 algorithm?

Tags: javascript, pdf, sha1, pdf.js

We are using the pdf.js (1.3.91) and pdf.worker.js. Our security ask me now, if I use the sha-1 algorithm in my or my third party code. But I cannot answer it. So my question here is:

> Did PDF and so mozillas pdf.js ever used the SHA-1 algorithm (e.g. password hashing)?
> If yes,
>   did pdf.js removed it?
> If yes, at what version?

Comment: What do you mean by 'use it', encrypting passwords and such shouldn't use it, but other uses should be fine, not sure why they are asking?

Comment: I think they mean encrypting passwords

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More context must be provided. I guess OP's security concern about weakness of SHA-1 as described at https://shattered.io/static/shattered.pdf

> Did PDF and so mozillas pdf.js ever used the SHA-1 algorithm (e.g. password hashing)?

Goal of any PDF viewer was to display a PDF no matter how broken and unsafe it is (and the Reader did set very "high" bar here⸮) So it's very unlikely any reader will remove SHA-1 algorithm for consumer by default.

> If yes, did pdf.js removed it?

There is no evidence of implementing SHA-1 in PDF.js by looking at https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/a8c87f8019aed3e9fcc5a7c2733ea3b8aa33e59a/src/core/crypto.js . Per [PDF32000](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf#search="SHA-1"), SHA-1 is used only for signature check and https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/1076 looks still opened.

So, no, pure SHA-1 did not make into PDF.js yet.

Comment: Thanks, this is just what i thought too.